# Icon to signify that an event is postponed

Tags: icon

I have 8-10 different event types that can be scheduled, completed, adjusted, postponed, etc.

What would be a good icon to signify that an event is postponed? I was thinking the loader icon, but I'm not 100% sold on it. A clock maybe?

Comment: I think most often a [clock with an alert](https://www.google.com/search?q=delay+icon&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4pKOE5oTgAhVii1QKHVHFADoQsAR6BAgGEAE&biw=1207&bih=1113) is used.

Comment: What's the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't like that you didn't show your attempts or explain why your previous efforts were what you were looking for. Sure I could have just posted a few icons already made, but I thought that I would help you get the ball rolling with your own ideas for the icon. [image]

1. postponed in time
2. postponed by time 2
3. postponed in cal
4. alarm postponed.

Comment: I was all over the place with my previous efforts. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A postponed event means that it must wait its turn to be made?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would have no idea what this means. It looks like a prize to me. Or a key card

Comment: I like the graphic! It's a ticket you would take at a deli to wait you turn for the butcher/meat slicer